# Refresh to remove all data from datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview in c#. The datasource is a List. all the fileds are being added as columns, at the end I add another column: DataGridViewLinkColumn,
If i do a refresh/reload the DataGridViewLinkColumn is being added more then once.
Any help would be much appriciated.

```
private void bidListToGridT(List<Item> list)
{
   dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
   dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
   dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
   dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
   int i = 1;
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
   {
      row.Cells["NO"].Value = i;
      i++;
   }
   dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Id";
   dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Name";

   DataGridViewLinkColumn Deletelink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
   Deletelink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
   Deletelink.HeaderText = "Delet";
   Deletelink.DataPropertyName = "lnkColumn";
   Deletelink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
   Deletelink.Text = "Delete";
   dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Deletelink);
   dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Avoid adding same column many times, Check whether such column existing in the gridview or not, Before adding them. For checking this you can use the following code.

```
bool hasDeleteColumn=false;
foreach (DataGridViewColumn  item in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
       if (item.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewLinkColumn) && item.HeaderText=="Delete")
          {
              hasDeleteColumn = true;
              break;
          }
    }
if(!hasDeleteColumn)
  {
    // Adding columns if not existing
    DataGridViewLinkColumn Deletelink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
    Deletelink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
    Deletelink.HeaderText = "Delete";
    Deletelink.DataPropertyName = "lnkColumn";
    Deletelink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
    Deletelink.Text = "Delete";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Deletelink);
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
  }
```